# Best way to separate python anywhere pymysql database connections using qgtunnel (quotaguard)?

Tags: mysql, python-3.x, pymysql, pythonanywhere

We are running 15-20 different python anywhere scripts that all talk to the same database.  The script are scheduled through different tasks that are sometimes running simultaneously and we get the following error when launching qgtunnel...

```
2022/05/16 12:52:11 Error initializing tcp socket 127.0.0.1:3306: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:3306: bind: address already in use

2022/05/16 12:52:11 Error initializing tcp socket 127.0.0.1:1433: listen tcp 127.0.0.1:1433: bind: address already in use
```

We thought about asking our mysql provider to have mysql listen on more ports but they don't allow that.  We also thought about having a different environment for each script but before we try that I wanted to ask if there's a better way.  Apprecite the advice.

Comment: Do you use PythonAnywhere MySQL server? Maybe send more details to support@pythonanywhere.com where someone can help you.

Comment: Mysql is hosted by another provider.  I will reach out to python anywhere but I'm wonder if it can be solved in the scripts themselves.

Comment: It looks like your code is trying to set up a local server for some reason rather than simply connecting to the remote DB.  Are you using an SSH tunnel, perhaps?

Comment: @GilesThomas, Yes, we're using qgtunnel.  I'm talking with quotaguard and they suggest we bind to different local ports for each script.  Once I get that nailed down I'll write an answer!

Comment: Yes, that sounds like a good way to do it :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after working with quotaquard their CTO had a great idea.  Before running each script overwrite the .qgtunnel settings files and specify your port.  I rolled that out to all the scripts and now I have no binding errors.  Overwriting the settings file looks like this...

```
cat <<EOF > /home/qgtunnel/.qgtunnel
[qgtunnel.Name_of_script_changing_file_sh]
accept = "127.0.0.1:5007"
connect = "host_url:3306"
encrypted = false
transparent = true
EOF

cd /home/qgtunnel ./bin/qgtunnel python3 ~/dir/python_script.py
```